# youtube to mp3 conversion on server

Tags: java, youtube, ffmpeg, xuggle

I'm wondering how can this site process file so quickly [youtube-mp3.org](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/). Could i use xuggler and convert to mp3 without downloading flv? Could i use [youtube-mp3.org](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/) in my program in order to download mp3 file from some youtube link. I'm trying to make server in java that has these capabilities and i could accomplish that just by downloading file and converting to mp3 but that isn't fast enough...

Comment: `you agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Website itself, the YouTube Player, or such other means as YouTube may explicitly designate for this purpose;`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect they are caching the conversion, so the first person that posts a youtube link has to wait for the download and convert, all subsequent users just get the already processed file immediately. If you have a lot of traffic the chances are someone already requested the same link you are requesting before.